# Overlapping sections with each other

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Every section is overlapping to the 'home-screen' section. Here's the live link [Hello Sylhet](http://hello-sylhet.com/new/).
But the page should be like this [image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the **question itself**. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is incorrect use of `position:absolute` property on `section#home-screen`. This section is being overridden by the elements coming after it. You need to push the elements further down using either `margin-top` or an empty `div`, so that `#home-screen` is visible.

Try this CSS:

```
#icon-search {
    margin-top:60%;
}
```

Try to modify the value of this property and the height of `section#home-screen` to get the display that you are seeking.

NB 1: As @Obsidian Age correctly mentioned in the comment, if you replicated your problem using JS Fiddle, Codepen or such, you would have got a precise answer with the code much quickly.

NB 2: If you want a piece of advice, don't position `#home-screen` as absolute. `position:absolute` is tricky, especially if it is not within a `position:relative` block element. Try to avoid it unless you `absolute`ly (pun intended) need to use it. Make the `#home-screen` a flexbox and then, push the next section up with a negative margin. Run the below snippet to see an example.

```css
.home-screen,
.icon-search {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.home-screen {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:60vh;
}
.icon-search {
  background-color:#fff;
  justify-content:space-around;
  margin: -25px auto 0;
  height:50px;
  width:90%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-screen">
  <div class="searchbox">Search me <input type="text"></div>
</div>
<div class="icon-search">
  <div class="icons">icon1 icon2 icon3</div>
</div>
```